# How to read rows from a text file into an array?

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a program which finds linear fitting, now I want to provide x elements from text file , y elements will remain the same , I want b(2) as a output for all 128 rows , which will be taken as input from trial2.txt

I want to read 128 rows which contains 3 columns, one by one and put those into x0[], then find b(2)

```
x0=[];


y0=[5.15659,5.48556,5.80477];


X1 = [ones(length(x0),1)  x0'];
b = X1\y0';
plot(x0,y0,'o')
y = b(1) + x0*b(2)
hold on
plot(x0,y,'--r')
fid=fopen('data.txt','a+');
fprintf(fid,'%10.1f %10.4f %10.4f %10.9f\n',x0,b(2));
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: You may check the [dlmread](https://docs.octave.org/v4.0.3/Simple-File-I_002fO.html#XREFdlmread) function

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get started with importing data into MATLAB is to use the interactive ["Import Tool"](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importtool.html). If you like the way it imports your data, you can get it to generate some re-usable MATLAB code so that you don't need to the use the UI next time round.